# How to edit and update the dynamically added input values

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

**Scenario:**

Below is my `json` file called `contacts`:

```
[
   {
     "name": "Ailis Wyld",
     "addresses": [
        {
            "addressType": "Business",
            "city": "Lansing",
            "postalCode": "48930"
        },
        {
            "addressType": "Home",
            "city": "Young America",
            "postalCode": "55573"
        }
     ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Aksel",
    "addresses": [
        {
            "addressType": "Business",
            "city": "Battle Creek",
            "postalCode": "49018"
        },
        {
            "addressType": "Home",
            "city": "Memphis",
            "postalCode": "38131"
        }
    ]
   },
   {
     "name": "Dearan",
     "addresses": [
        {
            "addressType": "Other",
            "city": "Minneapolis",
            "postalCode": "55417"
        },
        {
            "addressType": "Other",
            "city": "Sacramento",
            "postalCode": "95833"
        }
    ]
   }

]
```

I am displaying the `name` and `address` of the `contacts`(For ex one particular contact) like this:

[image]

**Expected Result:**

- I am displaying many `addresses`, If i click on particular `address`(For ex addressType: Home) i must able edit that `address` means i should get that address  values(i,e addressType, city, postalCode) in the below input fields like this:
  [image]

So that i can edit and update that particular address.

- Then i should be able add a new **address** from that input fields.

Below is my stackblitz **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-gjszmu?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this [online example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-u7tmvm?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

I changed these:

- use **Update mode** if an address is selected or **Add mode** if it is not
- *add* your form data to contacts array for a particular index
- *update* the selected address from your edit data

```js
  selectAddr(addr) {
    this.newAttribute.addressType = addr.addressType;
    this.newAttribute.postalCode = addr.postalCode;
    this.newAttribute.city = addr.city;

    this.selectedAddr = addr;
  }

  saveAddress(index, form: FormGroup) {
    const mode: 'update' | 'add' = this.selectedAddr ? 'update' : 'add';

    if (mode === 'add') {
      this.contacts[index].addresses.push({ ...this.newAttribute });
    } else if (mode === 'update') {
      Object.assign(this.selectedAddr, this.newAttribute);
    }

    // reset
    this.selectedAddr = undefined;
    form.reset();
  }
```

```html
<div class="main" *ngFor="let contact of contacts;let i = index">

<form [formGroup]="addForm" #myForm>

  <p>Name: {{contact.name}}</p>
  <br>
<!--Address section-->
      <div  class="address-sec">
        <p id="addr">Addresses</p>
        <br>
        <table style="width:100%" *ngFor="let addr of contact.addresses">
            <tr>
                <td>
                  <div id="field-type">
                      <mat-chip-list>
                        <mat-chip color="primary" (click)="selectAddr(addr)" selected>{{addr.addressType}}</mat-chip>
                      </mat-chip-list>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="field-data">
                   {{addr.city}}-{{addr.postalCode}}
                </div>
                  </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="field-data">
                    <b>Delete</b>
                   </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        <hr>
        <br>
      </div>
  <br>
  <!--Address Section-->

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select formControlName="addressType" placeholder="Type" [(ngModel)]="newAttribute.addressType">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let addressType of addresstypes" [value]="addressType.value">
            {{addressType.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
   
<br>
     
<mat-form-field >
    <input matInput formControlName="postalCode"  [(ngModel)]="newAttribute.postalCode"  placeholder="Postal Code" >
</mat-form-field>
<br>
<mat-form-field >
    <input matInput formControlName="city"  [(ngModel)]="newAttribute.city"  placeholder="City" >
</mat-form-field>
<br>

     <br><br><br><br>
        <button mat-flat-button    (click)="saveAddress(i,myForm)">Save</button>
</form> 
<br>
<hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution is working fine but one issue is there: when we edit one particular `address`.after that input fields should become empty on hitting `add` button, so that i can add a new `address` but it is not posaible in your link.

Comment: I update saveAddress(), you can see it in my change log

Answer (score 1):

When you work with a form in Angular then try accessing and working with data from form directives: `FormGroup`, `FormArray` etc.

In your code you've combined output of data from simple contacts array and tried then mix it with form controls.

Create form group for all the form correctly so that it matches your interface, then use data from it on the form, especially if you have an ability to modify it in form.

Using `formControl`s on inputs etc your data is being modified on user input so you can retrieve it with a `.value` property. When you group data in formGroups you can access all then aggregated data with `formGroup.value` where all the structure and data you created will be.

I've updated your stackblitz. With partially implemented what I've told. Continue in this way and you'll get maintainable and quite readable code.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-l6awjk?file=src/app/app.component.html

**Update**

Address edit example in stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-w9ty9b?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thanks for you responce, in you solutuon i am able to perform olny **delete**, but  i want perform add&edit also.

Comment: you need to use input or whatever with formControl directives to edit data. updated stackblitz for address: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-w9ty9b?file=src/app/app.component.html